# onkeyup is not firing whenever backspace is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onkeyup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>autoomplete</title>
<style>
.hidden1
{
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px; 
border: 2px solid  #00CC99; 
width: 200px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script> 
function showlist() 
{ 
if(!((/^\s*$/).test(edit1.value)))   
{ 
document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display="block";   
var tex=edit1.value; 
var name = new Array("python","django framework","mongodb");    
for(var i = 0;i< name.length;i++) 
{ 
if(name[i].indexOf(tex) != -1)   
{ 
add(name[i],name[i]);   
} } } } 
function add(Text,Value) 
{ 
var opt = document.createElement("option");  
listbox1.options.add(opt); 
opt.text = Text; 
opt.value = Value; 
} 
function selval(listval) 
{ 
edit1.value = listval.value; 
listval.style.display="none";
} 
</script> <body>
<div > 
<center>Autocomplete:<input type="text" id="edit1" name="edit1" onkeyup="showlist()"> </center>
</div> 
<div id="dropdown" style="display:none" align="center" > 
<select id="listbox1" size="3" name="listbox1" onclick="selval(this)" class="hidden1"> 
</select> </div> </body></html>
```

guys i've created an autocomplete text field using javascript.In browser autosuggestion box appears whenever the matching string is passed but  whenever i hit backspace the onkeyup was not firing and couldn't able to get autosuggestion which i had been created.please suggest a me a way to overcome this issue
thanx in advance!

Comment: function showlist() var tex=edit1.value; what is edit1 ?

Comment: getting the values of text field edit1.value(name.value) to the variable tex

Comment: Your `onkeyup` event is calling the function `showlist` and passing a parameter (this). However your `showlist` function does not accept parameters... Can you knock up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) for this please.

Comment: even passing that parameter to showlist function doesn't make hurdle but my query is onkeyup is not firing whenever backspace is hitted

Comment: change needed function showlist(dis) var tex = dis.value

Comment: your script breaks due to that

Comment: onkeyup is firing for backspace also.

Comment: @Harry bro plz check this out and ans

Comment: @Dineshdk: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/HRhPQ/). It logs 'ok' to console for every key-up event and you can see that it does when backspace is entered also. (Note: I have done changes similar to what shadow has mentioned above).

Comment: i have checked that bro in this code when executed on browser it doesnt working whenever bacspace is hitted

Answer (score 0):

**XHTML**

```
onkeyup="showlist(e)"
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showlist(e)
{//alert('e.keyCode = '+e.keyCode);
 var e = evt || event;
 var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

 switch (key)
 {
  case 8://Backspace
  alert('backspace pressed.');
  break;
 }
}
```